# In shiny app, HTML/Javascript loading new page instead of appearing within app

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I'm trying to embed a Google Trends image into a Shiny app, where I want the user to be able to dynamically change the country within the Shiny dashboard. The main problem is that the embedded javascript/html loads a new tab instead of appearing within the app. (javascript/html code coming when I click "embed" on one of the images [here](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=r%20shiny&geo=US)).

When I include the javascript/html text directly in the UI, it loads correctly within the Shiny App. When I try to pass the javascript/html from the server to the UI, it loads the new tab.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(

  h1("Test App"),
  fluidRow(
      column(4, align = "center", offset = 4,
             
             selectInput("choose_country",
                         "Choose Country",
                         choice = c("", "US", "NZ"),
                         selected = ""),

             uiOutput("html_out"),

             #### If we uncomment this, it shows up within page 
             #tags$body(HTML('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2213_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"r shiny","geo":"US","time":"today 12-m"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=r%20shiny&geo=US&date=today 12-m","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); </script>'))

      )
    )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$html_out <- renderUI({
    geo <- input$choose_country
    tags$body(HTML(paste0('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2213_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"r shiny","geo":"',geo,'","time":"today 12-m"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=r%20shiny&geo=',geo,'&date=today 12-m","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); </script>')))
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try embedding it to a `div` directly to avoid the document overwrite.  The function is called `renderExploreWidgetTo`. You'll need to add some JavaScript to select the `div` you want and add the `div` to your UI. Also, the script I used clears the previous chart each time it's called:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h1("Test App"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, align = "center", offset = 4,
           
           selectInput("choose_country",
                       "Choose Country",
                       choice = c("", "US", "NZ"),
                       selected = ""),
           ## this wrapper div is where the iframe will get embedded
           tags$div(id="wrapper"),
           
           uiOutput("html_out"),
                         
    )
  )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$html_out <- renderUI({
    geo <- input$choose_country
    tags$body(HTML(paste0('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2213_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> var divElem = document.getElementById("wrapper"); document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = ""; trends.embed.renderExploreWidgetTo(divElem, "TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"r shiny","geo":"',geo,'","time":"today 12-m"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=r%20shiny&geo=',geo,'&date=today 12-m","guestPath":"https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"}); </script>')))
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```